# Index of a vector field at a singular point and the order of the zero

Tags: differential-topology, riemannian-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Suppose $V$ is a smooth vector field on a compact Riemann surface $X$.  Let $x$ be a zero of order $n$ of $V$.

Is there any relation between the index of the vector field at $x$ and the order of $x$?

For example, if the order of $x$, $n$ is even, does this force the index of $V$ at $x$ to be even?

Comment: What's the definition of order please (vanishing lower derivatives?)

Comment: @PeterFranek  The order of a zero of $V$ is the order of the corresponding pole of the dual 1-form.  If $w$ is a 1-form, in local coordinates centered at $p\in X$, we write $w=f(z)dz$ where $f$ is a meromorphic function of the complex plane to itself. Then the order of $w$ at $p$ is the order of $f$ at $0$.